# Change select options with other select using JSON data - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I have a json data which looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 9,
    "category": "Baby",
    "items": "[{\"value\":\"Baby Foods\"}]",
    "created_at": "2022-01-08T14:28:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-08T14:28:48.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "category": "Adult",
    "items": "[{\"value\":\"Adult Clothes\"},{\"value\":\"Adult Bags\"},{\"value\":\"Adult Shoes\"}]",
    "created_at": "2022-01-09T10:46:34.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-09T10:46:34.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}]
```

It has a list of categories with its items. Now what I am trying to do now is to populate that data on select boxes in a way that if a user change category queried from JSON will show items (as shown on JSON) to another select box as options belonging to that category selected.

Here is what I have tried so far using jquery:

```
 let dropdown = $('#category');

dropdown.empty();
dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/show';

// Populate dropdown with list of categories
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.category).text(entry.category));
    })
});
```

Here is the result which shows categories on category select box perfectly:

[image]

I don't have idea how to get items if certain category is selected on another select box (second one) any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an eventHandler for your category `change` event, and whenver it changes, you can read related items from the source data, and put items in the target option, like this:

```js
let data = [{
    "category": "Baby",
    "items": "[{\"value\":\"Baby Foods\"}]",
  },
  {
    "category": "Adult",
    "items": "[{\"value\":\"Adult Clothes\"},{\"value\":\"Adult Bags\"},{\"value\":\"Adult Shoes\"}]",
  }
]

let categories = $('#category');
let items = $('#items')

function fillDropdown(target, {data, prop}) {
  $.each(data, function(key, data) {
    target.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', data[prop]).text(data[prop]));
  })
}

fillDropdown(categories, {data, prop: 'category'})

categories.on('change', function(e) {
  items.html('');
  let value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    let dataItem = data.find(v => v.category == value);
    const options = JSON.parse(dataItem.items);
    fillDropdown(items, {data: options, prop: 'value'})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="category">
  <option></option>
</select>
<select id="items"></select>
```

Comment: Hello @Saeed Shamloo. Thank you it works perfectly but only if I put JSON data on js. I need to load JSON from an external link. Can you assist me on that part? I've tried to do that and it brings a error

Comment: Hello, you're welcome. what is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/show

Comment: is your ajax response the same as data in the question? could you make a console.log and check your resopnse

Comment: Okay, let me see what's the problem but yes the response is the same

Comment: I would be glad if I could help

Comment: I've tried to pass the external JSON to data variable and it only shows categories but doesn't trigger the items once selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240885/discussion-between-saeed-shamloo-and-gxvr).

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you @Saeed Shamloo